# How to Latitude and Longitude in android

Tags: android, android-activity, locationmanager

I have developed simple application to display the latitude and longitude in android... but it is showing the null pointer exception... please let me know what is the error..

My Activity class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SignalStrengthActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

    private LocationManager  locationManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         if (location != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude and Longitude " + location.getLatitude() + " " + 
                        location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

         Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude and Longitude Offline ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {


    }
}
```

My Manifest file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.latitudelongitude"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.latitudelongitude.SignalStrengthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

when i execute the application it does not display anything.. indicating that the location object is null... please let me know how to fix the problem

Comment: where are you executing it ? in emulator or in device ? Emulator doesn't shows lat-lon values and in device you need to enable the gps to test above code.

Comment: You need to check it on real device and make sure that GPS is turned ON

Comment: What Raynold said is correct. You should test it on real device with GPS enabled. Note that it may take some time for GPS to get its first fix. If you want to test it on emulator then you have to send location coordinates to emulator. Check this link on how to send coordinates to emulator:                              http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/11/change-gps-location-of-android-emulator.html

Comment: Hi Nitish, Thanks for your reply.... i have installed it in android device and enabled GPS in the device...but still it is not displaying... but if i disable the GPS it says that GPS is offine...

How much time it will take to get its first fix approximately??(in my app.. it is not displaying even after 5 mins)

Comment: Well, there is no exact time within which GPS will get its first fix. Sometimes, it may take even less than 2 minutes while sometimes, it may take 10 minutes as well. Although, GPS is not biased by weather, but using it requires clear view of sky, means, suppose, if you are in basement of building or in your house, GPS may or may not get location updates as signals from satellite may be quite weak at these places. On the other hand, if you are driving or walking on the road,  you will notice that, you will get location updates faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the link below:

[Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)